# No questions in search results

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

It seems that the search feature currently only returns answers. Any `is:q` search finds zero results and omitting this, I only get answer results. I've confirmed this on Code Golf, Literature, Stack Overflow and here on Meta. I'm also surprised that this hasn't been reported yet, although there might be an older post about it... but to find out, I'd have to search for questions...

Comment: This also affects the close as duplicate dialog.

Comment: `is:q` is working for me [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq), [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq), [Codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq) and other sites too.

Comment: @Sinister The operator alone seems to be OK, but not if you add anything else to the search. For example, [this search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+duplicate) is broken.

Comment: [Related](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/910495256357081088)?

Comment: There's already a bug report on [meta.so] for this that's got better details... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356834/searches-with-isquestion-and-an-unquoted-string-dont-return-results

Comment: @Laurel But [it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq++duplicate%3Ayes+%22then%22+%5Bdesign%5D) is working for me even if I add other operators. I added tag, exact words. There should be some backgroup process going on. Look at Nick Craver's tweet and Bluefeet's comment on Meta.SO.

Comment: @Sinister Search definitely breaks when you add plain, unquoted words (again, see [this search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+duplicate)). But you're right that tags, operators, and quoted text do still work.

Comment: I think I've identified what's happening here, fix deploying now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fix is rolling out across the network and answered with a few details on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356836/13249).

TL;DR: Literally 1 character change, a bug we introduced in the Elastic v2 code branch was to blame...fixed and deploying now.